# Is there a prime factor that in the numerator of Bernoulli number $B_{2n}$ strictly greater than $2n$ for any $n>7$?

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

As well known, Bernoulli number $B_{2n}$ is a rational number which can always be shown as $B_{2n}=V_{2n}/A_{2n}$ , where $\gcd(V_{2n}, A_{2n})=1$.

For example, $B_{16}=\frac{3617}{-510}$ and $3617$ is exactly a prime factor greater than $16$.

$B_{20}=\frac{174611}{-330}$ and $174611=283*617$. Either $283$ or $617$ is a prime factor greater than $20$.

My Question: Is there a prime factor that in the numerator of Bernoulli number $B_{2n}$ strictly greater than $2n$ for any $n>7$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow. FYI, using a [site search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=%5Bbernoulli-numbers%5D+numerator+prime), there's the very similar [For a given even integer $k >14$ is there always a prime $p$ such that $k \leq p-3$ and $p|B_k$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/161066). It's asking, using your notation, if there's a $p\ge 2n+3$, so its only difference is it doesn't include $p=2n+1$. Note its only [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/277698) states, near the end, that Stephen V. Ullom "... showed that at most one-half of the $B_{2k}$ with $2k \le p-3$ are divisible by $p$, ...".

Comment: Also related to your question, the [Irregular Prime -- from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrregularPrime.html) states that "Equivalently, but more conveniently, an odd prime $p$ is irregular iff $p$ divides the numerator of a Bernoulli number $B_{2n}$ with $2n+1\lt p$". Also, there's "An infinite number of irregular primes exist, as proven in 1915 by Jensen (Vandiver and Wahlin 1928, p. 82; Carlitz 1954, 1968)".

Comment: It is possible to adapt the proof that the largest prime factor $P_{\alpha, \beta}(n)$ of Lucas sequences of the form $(\alpha^n - \beta^n)/(\alpha - \beta)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, satisfies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_{\alpha,\beta}(n) n^{-1} = \infty$ to help with this problem (see: On divisors of Lucas and Lehmer numbers, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11511-013-0105-y). Of course recurrences involving Bernoulli numbers are much more complicated.

Comment: @JohnOmielan :Thank you! The question you linked is indeed similar with mine. But it has not been well resolved until now.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao :Thank you! This is a new thinking and I will have a try.